# DOS Batch to rename and rotate folders name

Tags: batch-file, dos, rename, directory

I would like to rename and rotate the folders name with a DOS batch script.

Example:

I have this:

```
C:\Main\Folder01
C:\Main\Folder02
C:\Main\Folder03
C:\Main\Folder04
C:\Main\Folder05
```

I need to rename the Folder01 to be the last in the list, in the example it wil become Folder06. but it could be Folder50 depending of the quantity of folders. so i want to get this.

```
C:\Main\Folder02
C:\Main\Folder03
C:\Main\Folder04
C:\Main\Folder05
C:\Main\Folder06
```

Then i need to re index all the folders and to 01 02 03 04 05, so Folder02 will become Folder01 and in this way rotate all the folders.

I don't have a clue how to batch this, please advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would approach the problem a bit differently. It would be easier to first decrease all the numbers (including `01`) by one:

```
                  ┌─────> C:\Main\Folder00
C:\Main\Folder01 ─┘┌────> C:\Main\Folder01
C:\Main\Folder02 ──┘┌───> C:\Main\Folder02
C:\Main\Folder03 ───┘┌──> C:\Main\Folder03
C:\Main\Folder04 ────┘┌─> C:\Main\Folder04
C:\Main\Folder05 ─────┘
```

then rename the `00` folder to the former last name:

```
C:\Main\Folder00 ──┐
C:\Main\Folder01   │   C:\Main\Folder01
C:\Main\Folder02   │   C:\Main\Folder02
C:\Main\Folder03   │   C:\Main\Folder03
C:\Main\Folder04   │   C:\Main\Folder04
                   └─> C:\Main\Folder05
```

It seems easier this way because the loop renaming the folders would also be storing the last processed name in a variable, and that variable would afterwards be used to rename the `00` folder. Here's an implementation of what I am talking about:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "pathtemplate=C:\Main\Folder"
FOR /D %%I IN ("%pathtemplate%??") DO (
  SET "oldname=%%~nxI"
  SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  SET /A "newsuffix=1!oldname:~-2!-1"
  RENAME "%%I" "!oldname:~0,-2!!newsuffix:~1!"
  ENDLOCAL
)
RENAME "%pathtemplate%00" "%oldname%"
```

The `oldname` variable is the one that is used to remember the last processed folder after the loop. It is also used *in* the loop: first, for extracting the number, and second, for providing the base for the new name.

Comment: awesome!! it did work perfect! even if you did it in a different way, it does exactly what i meant to.. great! thank you..

Comment: @dbenham: Thanks! Now with pictures! :)